# Using Linked Queue dequeue method error cannot convert object to class

Tags: java

We are building a train station Simulator and when we started creating our methods we got errors  about our dequeue method.

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Passenger
package SimulateWaitingLine;

```
 public class Station {
        private QueueInterface waiting;
        private int timeToNextStation;
        public Station(int timeToNext){
            waiting = new CircularLinkedQueue();
            timeToNextStation = timeToNext;
        }
        public void addPassengers(Passenger rider){
            waiting.enqueue(rider);
        }
        public boolean isWaiting(){
            return !waiting.isEmpty();
        }
        public Passenger getPassenger(){
            return waiting.dequeue(); //this is where the error is
        }
        public int getTimeToNextStation(){
            return timeToNextStation;
        }
    }
```

here is our Definition of Linked Queue
package SimulateWaitingLine;

```
public class CircularLinkedQueue < T > implements QueueInterface<T>
{
    private Node queueNode;
    private Node freeNode;
    public CircularLinkedQueue()
    {
        freeNode = new Node();
        freeNode.setNextNode(freeNode);
        queueNode = freeNode;
    }
    private class Node
    {
        private T data;
        private Node next;
        public T getData() { return data; }
        public void setData(T inData) { data = inData; }
        public Node getNextNode() { return next; }
        public void setNextNode(Node inNext) { next = inNext; }

    }
    public void enqueue(T newEntry)
    {
    freeNode.setData(newEntry);
    if(isChainFull())
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        freeNode.setNextNode(newNode);
    }
    freeNode = freeNode.getNextNode();
    }
    @Override
    public T dequeue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        T front = getFront();
        assert !isEmpty();
        queueNode.setData(null);
        queueNode = queueNode.getNextNode();
        return front;

    }
    @Override
    public T getFront() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        T frontNode = null;
        if(!isEmpty())
            queueNode = queueNode.getNextNode();
        return (T) queueNode;


    }
    public boolean isChainFull() {
        return queueNode == freeNode.getNextNode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return queueNode == freeNode;

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the generic type of the queue to`Passenger`:

```
private QueueInterface<Passenger> waiting;
```

More on [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: we made that fixed the only problem is when it runs its not running correctly see here:

Comment: If that's solved you can mark this answer as accepted. As for your new problem - that may be a good follow-up question once you narrow the suspected code and share you stack trace.